# Sqlpackage.exe Deploy to Azure: Can I specify performance tier?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sqlpackage

When using SQLPackage.exe to deploy a DACPAC to an Azure SQL database, is it possible to specify the performance tier of the database to be created? Or do I need to create the database, then issue a separate command to downgrade/upgrade?

I've reviewed the (lengthy) documentation at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx and I don't see what I'm looking for. But it seems like a pretty obvious/desirable option, so maybe I'm missing something, or it's documented elsewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SqlPackage.exe does support setting up the **edition**, **performance level**, **maximum size** for Azure SQL Database as a part of publishing a dacpac to new database.

```
/p:DatabaseEdition = ({Basic | Standard | Permium | Default} 'Default') //Defines the edition of Azure SQL Database

/p:DatabaseServiceObjective = (STRING) // Defines the performance level of Azure SQL Database e.g. S0, S1, S2, S3, P1, P2, P4, P6, P11 

/p:DatabaseMaximumSize = (INT32) // Defines the maximum size in GB
```

Comment: Is this supposed to work for updating existing databases?  I would assume so, because the documentation does not specify only new databases.  However, when I tested this, it only worked on new.